# How do I route a request for a specific website outside of Cisco Anyconnect VPN?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, dns, cisco-anyconnect

Thanks for looking.

I am remotely doing some development work for a client and need to use their VPN to connect to their database and TFS server.

The VPN client is Cisco AnyConnect and I am told it uses a split tunnel.

I cannot connect to their public website when I am logged into their VPN.  I can still connect to any other website I wish.

This is a problem because to test the web application I am building for them, I need to be on their VPN so that I can access their database.  At the same time, I need to be able to access their website because there are hundreds of product images that are sourced from it.  In other words, I have to be able to display an image at "www.foo.com/images/someProductId.jpg" but can't because of the VPN issue.

Oddly, I was able to access their site while on VPN earlier today, but after logging off of the VPN for lunch and then back in, I now can't access their site again.

Is there a way for me to force any request for their public website to be made outside of the VPN tunnel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmmm....
If you are on windows machine try to edit

```
%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Be sure to have admin rights to edit this file.
Append next line in the end of file, change ip to ip of clients web server where site is located.

```
192.168.50.110    www.foo.com
```

If this not working you have to check "Default gateway" settings on your machine.
Like you can try to enable "Use remote gateway" on network interface which VPN creates,, to go through clients network.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks!  For anyone else that stumbles on this, the path is actually `%systemroot%\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

Comment: On my machine Windows 7 and %systemroot% opens C:\Windows